# Mailchimp - how to create a custom segment of a segment

Tags: mailchimp

I have an audience that I sent a message to.  Some time later I created a custom segment containing those whose campaign activity matched 'did not open' the original message.
I now want to repeat the process but only send to people who did not open the (first or) second message.  Is this possible please ?

Answer (score 0):

Embarassed that I was looking to tackle this in the wrong way.  The solution was to get a report of the non-openers (Activity > Didn't open) and export that as a .CSV.  Then just import that as a source for the required message.